# Connection-related exceptions occurr when attemping to login

Tags: xcode, ios9, ibm-mobilefirst

We have implemented a hybrid mobile app using latest version of MFP 7.0, also server side. Running the app on Mac with Xcode7 and testing in the iOS9 simulator  but it failed when making login action.

We used native code to get access to internal firewall, and then connect to WL server via WL.Client.connect, and we saw some exception print out on console of xcode as following:

> 2015-10-07 19:16:48.320 TestApp[7608:514098] [DEBUG]
>   [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper
>   requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:335 :: Response
>   Status Code : 403 2015-10-07 19:16:48.322 TestApp[7608:514098] [DEBUG]
>   [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper
>   requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:336 :: Response Error
>   : Expected status code in (200-299), got 403
>
> 2015-10-07 19:16:48.323 TestApp[7608:514098] [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST]
>   -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:477 :: Status code='403' error='Expected status code in (200-299), got 403'
>   response='/*-secure- {"reason":"App authenticity security check
>   failed"}*/' 2015-10-07 19:16:48.323 TestApp[7608:514098] [DEBUG]
>   [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:480 ::
>   Response Header: {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Language" = "en-US";
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Wed, 07 Oct 2015 11:16:44 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=97";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>       "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0"; }

Response Data:

> /*-secure- {"reason":"App authenticity security check failed"}*/
>   2015-10-07 19:16:53.064 TestApp[7608:514605] [ERROR] [NONE]
>   [/apps/services/api/TestApp/iphone/init] failure. state: 200,
>   response: undefined 2015-10-07 19:16:53.064 TestApp[7608:514170]
>   [DEBUG] [NONE] Client registration failed with error:
>   {"status":200,"responseHeaders":{},"responseText":"The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (WL_AUTH error 0.)","invocationContext":null}

Comment: 1) What is your MobileFirst Studio version **and build number**? 2) Are you using authenticity as shown in the error log? Is it Basic Authenticity or Extended Authenticity? 3) Did you disable Bitcode in the Xcode project? 4) Did you disable ATS or whitelisted your development server to connect would work?

Comment: 1) the version of MFP is 20150907-1450

Comment: 3) the bitcode in xcode was disabled
4) ATS was disabled also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a private chat, it was apparent that the failure is regarding Application Authenticity Protection which is actually not wanted to be used.

As such the solution to is verify that the authenticity security test is not being applied in the authenticationConfig.xml file, re-build the project to ensure to change is included in the generated .war file and to then re-deploy the updated .war file to the remote server in order to ensure that the server will not send an authenticity challenge as the application attempts to connect to the MobileFirst Server.

Comment: Thanks Idan, the issue resolved. After checking it caused by incorrect configuration of Authenticity Protection.